# How to use bind variables with Zend_Db_Table->update() in the where clause

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

If I want to use the `Zend_Db_Table->update()` method to update my table with data, I cannot find anyway to use bind variables in the "where" clause.

The method signature is:

```
int  update($data, array|string $where)
```

Usually you will call the method like this:

```
$table = new Bugs();

$data = array(
    'updated_on'      => '2007-03-23',
    'bug_status'      => 'FIXED'
);

$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('bug_id = ?', 1234);

$table->update($data, $where);
```

`quoteInto` is just going to escape the variable, not bind it.

There needs to be a way to use bind variables, otherwise a DBMS is not going to cache this query effectivly.

Am I missing something, or is this an oversight on Zend's part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only updating data, RDBMS (I assume MySQL) doesn't cache UPDATE queries. If you still want to use bind variables (security? performance?), you will have to use prepared statements:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET key = :key, value = :value");

foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    $stmt->bindParam('key', $key);
    $stmt->bindParam('value', $value);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

But unless you are having millions of UPDATE queries in a batch I don't think you should bother with this. Just use the *$table->update($data, $where);*

Comment: Thanks. I am using Oracle in an internal corporate application. You're correct, performance isn't an issue as such - I asked this question because I like to follow best practices where possible.

So I can either rewrite my code as you suggest or accept this limitation with Zend_Db_Table.

It's disapointing, because it is only the WHERE clause that is not bound - the SET clause does use bound variables under the hood. You would think they would provide a way to use bound variables for all parts of the query.