# Changing table name in Zend_db_select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

```
SELECT SUM(Table.ColumnThatChanges) AS 'Count', Table.B as 'Param'
FROM Table
WHERE Table.C = 4
    AND Table.B = 'Something'
    AND Table.Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-30 00:00:00'
```

I have this SQL Query that I generate in php. I want to call this query quite a few times with a slight change; I am changing ColumnThatChanges every request.

What would be the better/fastest way to do this? Use str_replace? Call the entire string everytime? Use some type of class that generates my SQL statement?

I'm currently generating it this way with Zend:

```
$somequery = $this->db->select();
$somequery->from(Table, array('SUM(Table.ColumnThatChanges) AS Count', 'Table.B as Param'))
->where('C = ?', $Variable)
->where('B = ?', $Variable2)
->where('Date > ?', $start_date)
->where('Date < ?', $end_date);
```

I haven't had much success changing the ColumnThatChanges part of the query, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `PDO` extension, there are [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) for this

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```

In Zend Framework it can be achieved using [Zend_Db_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html)

**UPD**
If you want to change columns, as it stated [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html), you can use `columns` method or second argument to `from` method;

```
$select = $db->select()
         ->from(array('p' => 'products'), 'product_id')
         ->columns('product_name');
```

Then if you want to change anything, all you need is to preserve your `$select` object.

**UPD-2** Bill Karwin has provided a better answer for a last version of the question. Please look at it.

Comment: I forgot to specify I'm using Zend. The code I'm currently working on uses Zend_Db_Select. Would that be an issue?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html Slightly different. But I'm not sure it allows me to change part of a statement once I've already stated it, I've tried without much success. I'm stuck with no choice but to recall the whole thing, which irritates me slightly.

Comment: @Sefam bumped link in the answer

Comment: @Sefam you wanna to change a column, not column value? Then `str_replace` is your best choice.

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry for the confusion. I'll make sure I include everything next time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56136/discussion-between-baldrs-and-sefam).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDO, you can bind parameters. So loop through your entries, and execute with the different data. I'm not sure if this is clear or not... ... oh wait, baldrs has an example. However, you can also pass an array to execute:

```
$stuff = array(':name' => 'one', ':value' => 1);
$stmt->execute($stuff);
```

Comment: I forgot to specify I'm using Zend. The code I'm currently working on uses Zend_Db_Select. Would that be an issue?

Comment: Ah, well that's similar to this question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604388/how-to-use-bind-variables-with-zend-db-table-update-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: You can't bind a column name as a parameter. Bounds parameters can be used only where you would normally use a string or numeric constant in an SQL expression.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote Zend_Db_Select for Zend Framework 1.0. There is no method to replace columns in the select-list, only to append or insert columns.

It's not hard to create a custom class to add this capability, though.

```
class My_Db_Select extends Zend_Db_Select
{
  public function clearColumns() {
    $this->_parts[self::COLUMNS] = array();
  }
}
```

Test out clearing the columns and adding different columns:

```
$sel = new My_Db_Select($db);
$sel->from("foo", array());

$sel->columns(array("SUM(foo.red)", "id"), "foo");
echo $sel . "\n";

$sel->clearColumns();

$sel->columns(array("SUM(foo.blue)", "id"), "foo");
echo $sel . "\n";
```

Output:

```
SELECT SUM(foo.red), `foo`.`id` FROM `foo`
SELECT SUM(foo.blue), `foo`.`id` FROM `foo`
```